# Whether it's possible to download a file and save it in a Chrome extension's directly?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to download a js file and save it directly to a Chrome extension's directory.(something like this file://xxxxxxx/common/a1.js)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Extensions are stored in directories in your computer's user profile, so you can download and save files into them like any other directory.

1. Find the ID of the Chrome Extension by navigating to `chrome://extensions/`.
2. Navigate to the extensions directory. It will be the name of the ID.

   **Mac:** `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/`

   **Windows:**`C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<PROFILE>\Extensions`, where  is your Windows username and `<PROFILE>` is the Chrome profile, which is `Default` if you didn't create any yourself.

   **Linux:**   ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/
3. Download the file and save it into the directory you discovered above.

Comment: I want to do it via Chrome

Comment: @Shan The question was not very clear. If you are asking whether you can initiate a download from within a Chrome Extension and download direct to it's own directory, then I don't think you can. The [chrome.downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download) only allows relative paths to the user's Downloads folder, and you can't go back up with `..`.

Comment: My entire idea was to download the files to a directly and use the same to display